# How to set up incoming stream in wowza from a file?

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, webrtc, wowza

The problem is simple.
There is an mkv file that is updating in real time.Say it is a destination for live video streaming so its size continuously is being increased.

Question - How can I set up this file as an incoming stream in wowza ?

Is it even possible ?

Can I configure this file in real time to any format that wowza supports ?

Comment: An mkv file is very abstract. MKV is a container. What is the video format? Share some metadata about the file? Maybe check if the still recording file plays in VLC for instance? You need to provide some more information to be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wowza does not currently support ingesting files in an MKV format. You can opt to try to re-stream the file using ffmpeg and then push it as an RTMP, RTSP, or MPEG-TS stream to Wowza.

For example, when pushing the MKV file as an RTSP stream with authentication to Wowza:

```
ffmpeg -re -i sample.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy -f rtsp rtsp://user:password@192.168.1.100:1935/live/myStream
```

Comment: Why use `-strict experimental`?

Comment: @Michelle-B - Thanks for your comment. I tried your command : 

ffmpeg -re -i 1459530099245.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy -strict experimental -f rtsp rtsp://192.168.0.32:1935/live/myStream

But it waits for sometime as shows error:

 [tcp @ 0x2f39300] Connection to tcp://192.168.0.32:1935?timeout=0 failed: Connection timed out

Comment: @LordNeckbeard thanks for pointing that out, I've removed it; Ankit, I tested out re-streaming a live stream (using ffmpeg) to an output.mkv file, and re-streamed the mkv file to a Wowza instance, and it worked fine for me. You may want to test it out first by streaming a static mp4 or mkv file and see if it works for you. You may also want to make sure that you disable any RTSP authentication on your Wowza application, as it may be auth-related.

Comment: @Michelle-B Yes it did work. thanks. The problem was the wowza IP was not reachable from the calling environment.

But now I am not able to play in the wowza. Bytes In seems fine with 1.700 Mb/S but I am not able to view in test players (Eg - In adobe HDS : Source stream or file could not be found or access was denied.)

Comment: Hi Ankit, have you tested with other playback formats, such as HLS? When you go into the Incoming Streams page of the Wowza Manager UI, and select the active Incoming Stream, clicking on Test Player should provide you with the correct playback URL for the different formats.

Comment: Should I run this ffmeg command from within the same server where wowza is installed. My wowza is set up on a windows server. And I ran this command from my machine in the LAN. Do you think it can create problem ?